# how to customize a progress bar using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

I was trying to creating a progress bar that was color coded in relation to the value. For example, from 0-35, the progress bar should be red-colored and above 35, green colored. Any idea how I can go about doing it?

```
If ProgressBar1.Value >= 35 Then
ProgressBar1.BackColor = Color.Green
Else
ProgressBar1.BackColor = Color.Red
End If
```

P.S in the same progressbar, both the colors have to shown based on the values

Comment: I tried the For and If statements but couldn't get it? :(

Comment: Would you mind showing what you come up so far?

Comment: @Edper - check my question above :)

Comment: By the way why you `ProgressBar1` and `ProgressBar2`? Is that correct or just a type from you?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible but you could only show one color at a time not two colors in one progress bar, unless you make it your own customize progress bar.

Comment: how can I create my own customized progressbar? And any idea where i can learn it

Answer (score 2):

You need to change settings on this one.

```
Go to Project --> [WindowsApplication] Properties

On Application Tab -- Uncheck Enable Visual Styles
```

However, be warned for there is a visual change on your progress bar as you will see.

You could then probably code like this:

```
If (ProgressBar1.Value > 35) Then
    ProgressBar1.ForeColor = Color.Red
Else
    ProgressBar1.ForeColor = Color.Green
End If
```

Comment: definitely works.. but is there a way to retain the visual styles AND do the color changes programmatically?
Levi's answer below doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

The position of the progress bar is stored in `ProgressBar1.value`. You can check this value in an `If` statement and change the color using `ProgressBar1.ForeColor`

eg:

```
If ProgressBar1.value > 35 Then
    ProgressBar1.ForeColor = Color.Lime
End If
```

I hope this helps ;)

**Edit:** Try using `ProgressBar1.ForeColor` rather than `ProgressBar1.BackColor`

Comment: thanks. But how can I store the position of the progress bar in ProgressBar1.value ?

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly use this method.

```
Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
Enum ProgressBarColor
    Green = &H1
    Red = &H2
    Yellow = &H3
End Enum
Private Shared Sub ChangeProgBarColor(ByVal ProgressBar_name As Windows.Forms.ProgressBar, ByVal ProgressBar_Color As ProgressBarColor)
    SendMessage(ProgressBar_name.Handle, &H410, ProgressBar_Color, 0)
End Sub
```

then add your condition statement by calling the function above e.g.

```
 If ProgressBar1.Value >= 35 Then
     ChangeProgBarColor(ProgressBar1, ProgressBarColor.Red)
 Else
     ChangeProgBarColor(ProgressBar1, ProgressBarColor.Yellow)
 End If
```