# How to change ProgressBar color in Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net

I want to change ProgressBar color in Visual Studio 2019, but find no properties. ForeColor seems not to work. Do you have a simple solution to change the color?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [how to customize a progress bar using vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20558871/1115360)?

Comment: The ProgressBar ForeColor and BackColor properties are only available in .Net Framework 1.1. This control uses a ProgressBarRenderer Class to paint the visual progress section, in chunks. The control part painting is delegated to the VisualStyleRenderer, initialized with `VisualStyleElement.ProgressBar.Bar.Normal`, which in turn calls [DrawThemeBackground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-drawthemebackground). The standard Theme color of this element is rendered. You need to create a custom Theme or create a Custom control and paint it yourself.

Comment: In this case, [ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.progressbarrenderer.drawhorizontalbar) can be used to render the external container of the ProgressBar, that you can then *fill* with something else (usually, these parts are drawn using the Graphics object provided by the `PaintEventArgs` argument of the `OnPaint` method override).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Andrew Morton. I have On Application Tab -- Enable Visual Styles unchecked. Backcolor works, but forecolor not.

*Progress_Daten.ForeColor = Color.Red* 
[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsxJs.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change ProgressBar with PictureBox, you can do this:

```
Public tempo As Integer = 0
Public kline As Double = 0
Public ktempo As Integer = 0
tempo = Math.Round(Timer1.Interval / 1000)
Timer3.Start()
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1M4P.png)

```
Private Sub Timer3_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer3.Tick
'ProgressBar with intervall 1000 milliseconds
If ProgressBar1.Value < tempo Then
    ProgressBar1.Value += 1
Else
    ProgressBar1.Value = 1
End If

'With PictureBox
Dim b2 As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b2)
Dim br As Brush = New Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 128, 255)) 'color progressbar
Dim sr As Brush = New Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.Black)                   'color string %
PictureBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle                       'border progressbar


Dim stepline As Double = PictureBox1.Width / tempo      'step of progress
Dim rect2 As Rectangle = New Rectangle()                'rectangle of progress
rect2.Size = New Size(kline, PictureBox1.Height)        'size progress

g.Clear(Color.Black)                                    'background color progress
g.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality   'high quality
g.FillRectangle(br, rect2)                              'progressbar
'insert draw string here

If ktempo < tempo - 1 Then                              'tempo control
    kline += stepline
    ktempo += 1
Else
    If kline >= PictureBox1.Width - 1 Then
        kline = 1
    End If
    kline = 1
    ktempo = 0
End If

PictureBox1.Image = b2
PictureBox1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

LordMarte